# How to write conditional If Statement in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can I combine  two if condition in one statement in Lightning components.

```
<aura:if  isTrue="{!v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Pay_Element_Master__c'}">
            <aura:if  isTrue="{!v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='CTC_Master__c'}">
                 <aura:if  isTrue="{!v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Section_Master__c'}">
                <lightning:select name="select" label=" " aura:id="o" >
                    <option value="">None</option>
                </lightning:select>
            </aura:if>
        </aura:if>
        </aura:if>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try lightning **and** function

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm

```
<aura:if  isTrue="{!and(v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Pay_Element_Master__c', 
                        v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='CTC_Master__c', 
                        v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Section_Master__c')}">
    <lightning:select name="select" label=" " aura:id="o" >
        <option value="">None</option>
    </lightning:select>
</aura:if>
```

**Above code is not working now.**

### Updated code - 20-02-2018

```
<aura:if  isTrue="{!and(
                        and(v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Pay_Element_Master__c', v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='CTC_Master__c'), 
                        v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme!='Section_Master__c')
                    )}">
        <lightning:select name="select" label=" " aura:id="o" >
            <option value="">None</option>
        </lightning:select>
    </aura:if>
```

You can wrap one `and` condition inside another since lightning `and` function work with only 2 parameters. below is the example

```
{!and( and(condition 11, condition 12), condition 2)}
{!and( and( and(condition 111, condition 112), condition 12), condition 2)}
```

**Note: Since it is javascript, don't user capital AND. Use only small and**

Comment: your welcome @AnnappaPH

Comment: Sorry to only read this a year later. If this code is live in your org the logic may be wrong. Actually the Lightning expressions `and`, `or` only take two arguments and ignore any after the 2nd. You can use `&&` for AND but in Lightning markup it must be XML-escaped, so it will actually be `&amp;&amp;`.

Comment: Someone minused my comment after I entered it. Please refer here for further confirmation that `and(param1,param2,param3)` in Lightning is treated as only `and(param1,param2)`. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176835/is-there-a-limit-to-lightning-formula-parameters/205341#205341 *"Yes, it's a known bug/limitation of Expression Operators. You can only evaluate two parameters in and and or expressions."*