# Is There a Limit to Lightning Formula Parameters?

Tags: lightning, formula, aura, aura-if

As I use the client side to enforce various pieces of business logic with aura:if statements, I'm finding that a given formula operator cannot handle more than two parameters.

For example, this works:

```
<aura:if isTrue="and(v.myAttributeString == 'Open', v.myAttributeBoolean == true)">
    //do some stuff
</aura:if>
```

But the following does not work (or at least the third "v.myAttributeSecondString" is not evaluated):

```
<aura:if isTrue="and(v.myAttributeString == 'Open', v.myAttributeBoolean == true, v.myAttributeSecondString == 'Yes')">
    //do some stuff
</aura:if>
```

Has anyone seen the same effect occur? Any documentation on this? Am I crazy and this actually does work, just not for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it's a known bug/limitation of Expression Operators. You can only evaluate two parameters in `and` and `or` expressions. You'll probably want to consider setting an attribute evaluated by your controller to determine the final logic behavior as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a reference to the known issue for tracking purposes?

Comment: @techbusinessman "Known Issue" might be a bit strong. I know that it's broken, and that people at salesforce.com know it's broken, but I don't know of a public Known Issue that you can sign up for. Perhaps you should submit a case and see if Dev Support will give you one.

Answer (score 6):

Two things to add:

1) From a JavaScript perspective it makes sense. In JS extra parameters to a function are accepted and ignored. So `and(true, true, false)` returns `true` because it's a two-parameter function.

2) For what it's worth, you can chain any number of ANDs with `&&` but unlike Visualforce you have to escape it to conform with XML rules. So `{!true &amp;&amp; true &amp;&amp; false}` correctly yields `false`. Note that for chaining multiple ORs you can just use `||` straight up.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with [@Sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) And nice options from [Charles T](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/33406/charles-t)

So there is one more solution that I follow

You can wrap one `and` condition inside another since lightning `and` function work with only 2 parameters. below is the example

```
{!and( and(condition 11, condition 12), condition 2)}
{!and( and( and(condition 111, condition 112), condition 12), condition 2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official documentation regarding these limitations:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_operators.htm

"If you have more than two arguments, you can chain multiple && operations."

"If you have more than two arguments, you can chain multiple || operations."